# Default Shutdown Order of Windows Services

Tags: windows, service

While I could find articles on how the windows services start in an order that is based on service groups and within a service group based on tags, I am unable to get information on the default shutdown order of windows services.

If we do not specify a "PreshutdownOrder" to alter the shutdown sequence, can we assume that windows services would shutdown in an order that is reverse of the order in which they start? If no then why is it so and how is the shutdown order determined? If yes then can you please point me to relevant documentation preferably from Microsoft?

I am asking this question because I have an application whitelisting service (say A) on my machine that belongs to a service group and a few services (say B and C) that do not belong to any service group. For system security reasons, I want to ensure that whitelisting service A starts before other services start and shuts down after other services shut down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Service Control Handler Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685149(v=vs.85).aspx) on MSDN:

> After the preshutdown notifications have been completed, all control handlers that have called SetServiceStatus with the SERVICE_ACCEPT_SHUTDOWN control code receive the SERVICE_CONTROL_SHUTDOWN control code. They are notified in the order that they appear in the database of installed services.

I believe the upshot of that is that the order in which services are notified is unpredictable.  Of course, the services do not necessary stop in the order in which they are notified; the system does not wait for each service to stop before notifying the next one.

Based on your description, in your scenario the best option would probably be for service A to continue running during the system shutdown.  Any service that does not register for shutdown notification is simply left running until the system is actually powered down or restarted.

However, if it is essential that service A is notified that the system is shutting down (for example, it might need to close a database file cleanly) then it can return STOP_PENDING while it waits for all of the dependent services to stop.

Comment: Thank you Harry for your response. Actually service A is a third-party commercial software and I do not have control over or access to its source code. However services B, C and so on have been developed in-house. Let me investigate "PreshutdownOrder" setting to see if it would help.

Comment: The documentation isn't very clear about the effects of PreshutdownOrder.  You'll probably need to experiment.  But according to the documentation the system does wait for services that register for preshutdown notification to exit before starting on the services that don't.  So if A doesn't have ACCEPTS_PRESHUTDOWN set (which you can check using `sc query` on the command line) you just need to set ACCEPTS_PRESHUTDOWN on your other services.

Comment: Thanks again Harry. Through your `sc query` suggestion, I was able to find out that service A accepts shutdown and since other services are developed in-house we can make them accept shutdown as well. Therefore I believe I should be able to control the order of shutdown through "PreshutdownOrder" registry setting.

Comment: I think you'll need to make your services accept preshutdown notifications rather than shutdown notifications.  But you can experiment.

Comment: Sharing my latest observations. While service A accepts shutdown notifications, it does not accept pre-shutdown notifications. I modified service B to accept pre-shutdown notifications and was able to delay the shutdown of service B. Irrespective of the order of service A and B in the "PreshutdownOrder" registry setting, based on my limited testing service B always shutdown before service A. Even when service A and B are removed from the "PreshutdownOrder" registry setting, service B shutdown before service A.